# How do I map a network drive in Ubuntu? I want to save my Firefox downloads directly in the mapped network drive (folder)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I work in an environment wherein files are exchanged over email which are then processed into databases.

In Windows, mapping a network drive and storing files directly to a folder in the network drive from Firefox/Chrome downloads is a breeze.

How to achieve the same in Ubuntu? I don't see the SFTP'ed drive/directory as options in Firefox-> Downloads setup.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate (same user): http://superuser.com/questions/135316

Comment: It happened in realtime. They moved and I posted all at the same time. Feel free to delete. Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Gnome...

1. Go to the *Places* menu, then *Connect to Server...*
2. Connect how ever you'd like (SSH, Windows share, etc)
3. In Firefox, browse to your home directory, to **.gvfs** (right-click on the file listing and enable *Show Hidden Files* if necessary)
4. There will be a directory for the folder you just connected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map Windows Network drives, then there is `smbmount` for that purpose (I think it is automatically comes with the smbclient package). If you want to map a network drive through SSH, then `sshfs` is for you (you have to install it separately from ssh).